# Floating button in Android application (Paging View)

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

I have an iPhone application which pages through a series of images.  I use the following code to place a floating help button in my view controller, it stays in the same position on the screen as the user pages through the images:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Help.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(viewHelp)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        button.frame = CGRectMake(60.0, 60.0, 210.0, 80.0);
        CGRect buttonFrame = button.frame;
        buttonFrame.size = CGSizeMake(70, 70);
        button.frame = buttonFrame;
        NSLog(@"IPAD");
    }
    else {
        button.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, 60.0, 40.0);
        CGRect buttonFrame = button.frame;
        buttonFrame.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45);
        button.frame = buttonFrame;
    }


    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

I'm wondering how one can achieve the same functionality in an Android app?  Below is my current layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone give me any pointers?

**EDIT:** I would like to place the button just off-set of the top-left corner.

Comment: Which position do you want to place the button? TOP-LEFT? TOP_RIGHT? or Custom(X,Y)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a relative layout, which will place the `ImageButton` on top of the `ViewPager` something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/help" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would always recommend using a Relative Layout. Inside a RelativeLayout you can freely place Views, and they also can overlap.

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:alignParentTop="true"
        android:alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout shows the ViewPager and a button floating in the upper right corner.